# Why can't I select image in Users folder to upload in user profile dotnetnuke?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

Im add new attribute to user profile on dotnetnuke, the attribute is Avatar which type is Image. Everything is ok without changing its picture, I go to Manage Profile page, and select one of pictures I uploaded before in Users folder. But everytime I selected new image, the site is always reset to  value! (Im using dotnetnuke 5.4)
Does anybody know why ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the user profiles in DotNetNuke. It is being addressed in the next release, 6.1, coming out later this fall.